# AsyncPostBackTimeout not updating data in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to update data inside update panel without postback.

I made following code on aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="30">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

for updating the label on every half a minute, i written following code on pageload:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCount.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }
```

But its not updating the label even though i given

```
AsyncPostBackTimeout="30"
```

in script manager.

Is anything i am  mistaking??

I want to update label inside the updatepanel without postback on certain time interval.

**Edit:**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>


            <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>.

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your your page every 30 seconds you can use a timer:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script runat="server" type="text/c#">
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCount.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
</script>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="30">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="30000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
         <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" Text="Page not refreshed yet."></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

As @Nipun Ambastha suggested add the `AsyncPostBackTrigger` trigger.

Without `AsyncPostBackTrigger`, the timer has to be placed inside the `UpdatePanel`:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " +
DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager2">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer2" Interval="30000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Page not refreshed yet." ID="Label1">
            </asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" ID="Label3"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Comment: But it is postbacking(Refreshing) the page... i dont want to refresh the page every time

Comment: I want to refresh just a panel or label

Comment: "asynchronous postback event is not a known element" this error is there

Comment: "asynchronous postback event is not a known element"  you get this error if you place Triggers inside the ContentTemplate

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not using Async Trigger, for updating a panel you will need to declare Async Trigger.

Please check this url
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

More Detailed
http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx